# removing duplicate lines from file with grep

Tags: unix-shell

I want to remove all lines where the second column is 05408736032.

```
0009300|05408736032|89|01|001|0|0|0|1|NNNNNNYNNNNNNNNN|asdf|
0009367|05408736032|89|01|001|0|0|0|1|NNNNNNYNNNNNNNNN|adff|
```

Comment: Double posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439816/removing-duplicate-lines-from-file-grep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might do what you want:

```
sort -t '|' -k 2,2 -u  foo.dat
```

However this sorts the input according to your field, which you may not want. If you really only want to remove duplicates, your best option is Perl:

```
perl -ne '$a=(split "\\|")[1]; next if $h{$a}++; print;' foo.dat
```

Answer (score 9):

```
awk -F \| '{if ($2 != 05408736032) print}'
```

Comment: You can leave out the "if" and the "print": `awk -F \| '$2 != "05408736032"'`

Answer (score 1):

Pure Bash:

```
oldIFS=$IFS
while read line
do
    IFS=$'|'
    testline=($line)  # make an array split according to $IFS
    IFS=$oldIFS       # put it back as soon as you can or you'll be sooOOoorry
    if [[ ${testline[1]} != "05408736032" ]]
    then
        echo $line
    fi
done < datafile
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it that you want to remove all lines where the second | separated field contains '05408736032'? Will all the lines be formatted the same? If so, this should output the file minus those lines (it's perl that takes the original file as the first argument and the file it's going to as the second).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
my  ($file1, $file2) = @ARGV;
open my $origin_file, '<', $file1;
open my $newfile, '>', $file2;
while (my $line = <$origin_file>) {
    my @values = split '/|/', $line;
    print $newfile $line unless $vaules[1] = '05408736032';
}
close $newfile or die $!;
close $origin_file or die $!;
```

(I haven't tested this, so you probably want to backup the original file before you try it)

On reading again, you may be looking to grab only lines with a unique second column. This should do that.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
my  ($file1, $file2) = @ARGV;
open my $origin_file, '<', $file1;
open my $newfile, '>', $file2;
while (my $line = <$origin_file>) {
    my @values = split '/|/', $line;
    print $newfile $line unless defined $unique{$values[1]};
    $unique{$vaules[1]} += 1;
}
close $newfile or die $!;
close $origin_file or die $!;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
for f in `cat $file`; do 
  val=`echo $f | cut -d\| -f 2`
  if [ `grep $val $file | wc -l` -lt 2 ]; then
     echo $f
  fi
done
```

but, like most shell scripts, it's pretty inefficient. You'd be better off doing it in perl, something like:

```
@infile=<>;

foreach (@infile) {

  @foo = split(/|/);
  if exists $found{$foo[1]} {
    $found{$foo[1]}++;
  } else {
    $found{$foo[1]}++;
  }

}

foreach (@infile) {
  @foo = split(/|/);
  if ($found{$foo[1]} < 2) {
    print $_;
  }
}
```